# Enum within struct - Scope of enum in C

Tags: c, struct, enums

Why I can use the enum "outside" the struct as a parameter of the init function? So it looks like the enum is global and not restricted to the enclosing struct block.

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    enum color_t {r, g, b} color;
} point;

void myfunc(point *this, enum color_t c) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Because C is not C++.  You could define a structure type within another and both are usable.

Comment: From the dupe: "In C, there is simply no rule for scope for enums and struct. The place where you define your enum doesn't have any importance." Please search next time for duplicates @knowledge, since they don't seem to be so rare about your question!

Comment: @gsamaras Unfortunately your quotation from selected answer on that question is incorrect. [Scope is determined by the placement of the struct definition.](https://ideone.com/btYDin)

Comment: Are you saying that the answer in the dupe is wrong? If so, please let the poster now. Moreover, if it's indeed wrong, then I should unmark the dupe, but I really have no time to contribute more now

Comment: @gsamaras I left comment on that answer. I don't know if removing dupe is necessary; second answer on that question is closer to truth.